# After styling TableView Scroll i get a warning in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I'm styling the handler in a TableView Component using the following code:

```
TableView {
    style: ScrollViewStyle{
        handle: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: globals.scrollBar.handlerWidth
            implicitHeight: globals.scrollBar.handlerWidth
            color:  globals.scrollBar.handlerColor
        }
    }
}
```

The properties are:

```
property var scrollBar: QtObject {
    property int handlerWidth: 14
    property color handlerColor: "#6b6b6b"
}
```

I tried switching `int` and `color` to `var` but i still have the same problem.

Globals are defined on main, like this:

```
Globals {
    id: globals
}
```

Now i'm getting a lot of warnings in QT

```
file:///C:/Qt/5.11.1/mingw53_32/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Private/BasicTableView.qml:393:48: Unable to assign [undefined] to bool
file:///C:/Qt/5.11.1/mingw53_32/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Private/BasicTableView.qml:97:38: Unable to assign [undefined] to QQmlComponent*
file:///C:/Qt/5.11.1/mingw53_32/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Private/BasicTableView.qml:461:20: Unable to assign [undefined] to QColor
```

What am i missing?

A minimal functional example creating an empty qt (5.12) application with qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
    import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Stack"
    visible: true
    width: 1400
    ListModel {
        id: libraryModel
        ListElement {
            title: "A Masterpiece"
            author: "Gabriel"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Brilliance"
            author: "Jens"
        }
        ListElement {
            title: "Outstanding"
            author: "Frederik"
        }
    }

    Page {
        id: page
        anchors.fill: parent
        background: { color:"black" }
        TableView{
            style: ScrollViewStyle{//TODO:  ScrollViewStyle is giving a lot of warnings
                handle: Rectangle {
                    implicitWidth: 15
                    implicitHeight: 15
                    color:  "#000000"
                }
                minimumHandleLength: 30
            }
            anchors.fill:parent
            TableViewColumn {
                role: "title"
                title: "Title"
                width: 100
            }
            TableViewColumn {
                role: "author"
                title: "Author"
                width: 200
            }
            model: libraryModel
            itemDelegate: Text
            {
              text: styleData.value
              elide: Text.ElideRight
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe the error/warning is related to imcompatibly imports?

Comment: how have you implemented globals?, it seems to me that the error is caused by your implementation and/or invocation of globals

Comment: @eyllanesc i've edited the post to show the implementation of the variables

Comment: globals is a singleton? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @eyllanesc no, globals is another .qml file accessible through main. I've provided a minimal, complete and verifiable example that still gives error, and doesn't use any file for styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [TableView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html) then you must use [TableViewStyle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-tableviewstyle.html) instead of [ScrollViewStyle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-scrollviewstyle.html). and you can continue using the same properties since [TableViewStyle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-tableviewstyle.html) inherits from [ScrollViewStyle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-scrollviewstyle.html):

```
style: TableViewStyle{
    handle: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 15
        implicitHeight: 15
        color:  "#000000"
    }
    minimumHandleLength: 30
}
```

---

Remove the following line of code since background expects a Component, but it is also unnecessary since TableView will occupy the entire Page:

```
background: { color:"black" }
```

Comment: @Nmaster88 You see with a [mcve] it's easier to help